# Can Jenkins be backup just with config and jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I want to do an automatically backup of the `JENKINS_HOME` but due to file size I just want to copy the config.xml and /jobs.

Is it possible to restore Jenkins if needed with just those two things? How is the process to do it? Just replacing the config.xml and /jobs and restarting the service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Jenkins SCM Sync configuration plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin) - it allows to back up all your Jenkins settings (including job configurations) to git or SVN. Also, version control means you'll have an easier time debugging problems caused by configuration changes or to revert to an older configuration.

Comment: Yeah, I know that there are several plugins that would work, but I want to know if this approach can work and if it is a safe way of doing it or it may cause errors.